# reading data from stackoverflow rest api

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x

Playing around with the raspberry pi and python. so bear with me :)

When trying to decode the response data from the stackoverflow api I keep on receiving the error `utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

Here is the entire code that I have hacked up at the moment

```
import http.client
import json
import zlib

c = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.stackoverflow.com')
c.request('GET', '/1.1/questions?answers=true&page=1&pagesize=5&tagged=sql')
r = c.getresponse()

compressedData = r.read()
uncompressedData= zlib.decompress(compressedData, 15+32)

data = str(compressedData, 'utf-8')
print(data)
```

But the response data is encoded in utf-8 format? Not quite sure why this is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine but...

```
data = str(compressedData, 'utf-8')
```

you're trying to decode the *compressed* data.  Try decoding the uncompressed data :-)